# How to save a bitmap as a 8-bit-per-pixel jpg image?

Tags: c#, bitmap, jpeg, gdi+

I am trying to save a bitmap to a 8-bits-per-pixel jpg Image using C#.NET, this is my program:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(500, 500, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
bitmap.Save("img.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp); //this saves a 8bpp bmp image
bitmap.Save("img.png", ImageFormat.Png); //this saves a 8bpp png image
bitmap.Save("img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); //this saves a 24-bpp jpg image
```

I check the pixel format using the file Properties window (right click on file -> Properties -> Details tap -> Bit Depth field). I check the file format using http://checkfiletype.com/

Comment: okay, and? are you getting an error? are you getting exactly what you want? you need to provide more information.

Comment: According to this answer, you can't. [Converting to real 8bpp Jpeg](//stackoverflow.com/a/24871861)

Comment: @DetectivePikachu sorry if it is not clear, I wrote the output for each line as a comment.

Comment: I think 8bpp jpeg is only grayscale. The framework does not support that format.

Comment: @Nyerguds Yes, I needed to convert a colored bitmap to grayscale jpg image, there was no way to do that using the Bitmap.Save() method, I used the FreeImage.ConvertToGrayscale() and it worked just fine.

Comment: If converting an image to grayscale was the only purpose, there _are_ simpler methods of doing that...